# EasyAdmin : custom type for a field

Tags: forms, symfony, easyadmin

I would like to use a custom Type of mine for a field in an EA managed entity.

I'm using SF Flex so my type is autowired and setup as service correctly (appears with `debug:container`).

Now, I would expect to do something like below in `easy_admin.yaml` :

```
    Menu:
        class: Lch\MenuBundle\Entity\Menu
        help: 'admin.site.menu.help'
        controller: App\Controller\Admin\Site\MenuController
        list:
            fields:
                - title
                - location
        form:
            fields:
                - title
                - location
                - { property: menuItems, type: 'lch_menu_tree' }
```

I found [in documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html#customize-the-form-fields) that you can't put anything in here but native Type or EA ones.

How can I setup EA to make it use my type for this particular field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use its fully qualified class name as expected for custom form type, e.g:

```
- { property: menuItems, type: 'App\Form\Type\LchMenuTree' }
```

You can use the short type name while it's a known type for EasyAdmin. The list of mapped types is [here](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/7648b0c162eb4b6debc0fc9fcb1712a0c6d4cd5c/src/Form/Util/FormTypeHelper.php#L56). Otherwise, you must to provide its FQCN as required by the Form component.